# Repeated Random Numbers

Tags: python, random, integer

I have created a bingo game where random numbers are generated and called for a list.

```
bingo_num = random.randint(1,100)
```

How would I stop a random number being generated more than once

Comment: How many random numbers do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it the same way they do it in a *real* Bingo game. They do not roll dices, but put all the numbers in a big bag, shake it, and pull out numbers one at a time, until all the numbers are used up.

```
numbers = list(range(1, 101)) # all the numbers in the bag, from 1 to 100
random.shuffle(numbers)       # shake the bag
bingo_num = numbers.pop()     # pull out next number (inside your loop)
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest, [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
from random import shuffle
my_list = range(100)
shuffle(my_list)
print my_list
```

But if you need only specific amount of unique numbers, you can use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample), like this

```
from random import sample
my_list = range(100)
print sample(my_list, 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can take a [sample](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) of a range from the random library

```
>>> import random
>>> nums = random.sample(range(0,200),100)
>>> nums
[143, 149, 52, 183, 161, 179, 180, 155, 163, 157, 139, 15, 154, 181, 56, 29, 31,
 14, 77, 82, 165, 32, 35, 92, 109, 172, 69, 99, 54, 3, 88, 76, 11, 126, 78, 162,
 198, 145, 124, 75, 114, 174, 136, 100, 190, 193, 148, 153, 167, 113, 38, 17, 16
8, 0, 196, 73, 47, 164, 184, 6, 140, 30, 58, 74, 4, 79, 147, 178, 191, 21, 112,
13, 27, 57, 199, 116, 28, 104, 111, 71, 23, 85, 170, 25, 141, 156, 91, 7, 182, 1
34, 94, 169, 175, 166, 137, 160, 129, 36, 67, 135]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first create a list containing all possible numbers. Then pick a random number from that list, add that to a result list and finally remove it from the list of possible numbers.

For example if you want 5 different numbers from `0-9`:

```
possible_numbers = range(10)
numbers = []

for i in range(5):
    index = random.randint(0, len(possible_numbers) - 1)
    numbers.append(possible_numbers[index])
    del possible_numbers[index]
```

Comment: random.shuffle does that better, I think.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: You're right. I thought of this solution before reading the other answers and thought I'd keep it. To me this is the most straightforward way of doing it if you don't know about `shuffle` or `sample`. While this is not the most elegant way to do it, it's certainly not bad to know how to do it yourself. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
numbers = []
while len(numbers) < 100:
    bingo_num = random.randint(1,100)

    if not bingo_num in numbers:
        numbers.append(bing_num)
```

Comment: This takes quadratic time even if `random.randint` never generates any number twice, and much longer if it does.

Comment: @delnan That is true, it is not efficient. Given the application (a bingo draw) it probably is acceptable though.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new number if already in use

advantage: easy code

disadvantage: will run long if nearly all numbers are use (there are better solutions)

Sample code:

```
bingo_num_list = []

# init num
bingo_num = random.randint(1,100)

# create new numbers till "find" a not used one
while bingo_num in bingo_num_list:
    bingo_num = random.randint(1,100)

bingo_num_list.append(bingo_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Build list of all the numbers then select a random 1, remove it from the list then select the next one:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random

myNumz=[]
xIdx=1
while xIdx<101:
myNumz.insert(xIdx,xIdx)
    xIdx+=1

xIdx=100
while xIdx>0:
    xIdx-=1
    baseNum=random.randint(0,xIdx)
    print myNumz[baseNum]
    myNumz.remove(myNumz[baseNum])
```